# Dependency Injection : Could not initialize class org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults

Tags: java, spring

I'm developping a Java library that uses Spring framework.
On this library I created a class that will act as application manager. It uses the singleton design pattern.

This class uses dependency injection for external HTTP calls.

```
public class SharePointManager {
    private static SharePointManager instance = null;
    private static IAuthenticationResult iAuthenticationResult;
    private static String token;
    private static SiteService siteService;

    public static SharePointManager getInstance() {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context =
                new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        SharePointManager.dummyService = context.getBean(DummyService.class);
        SharePointManager.siteService = context.getBean(SiteService.class);
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new SharePointManager();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private SharePointManager() {
    }

    public SharePointSiteResponse getAllSites(SharePointCredentialRequest creds) throws Exception {
        if( iAuthenticationResult != null && iAuthenticationResult.accessToken() != null ) {
            token = iAuthenticationResult.accessToken();
            if (Utils.checkToken(iAuthenticationResult.accessToken())) {
                token = Utils.getToken(creds).accessToken();
            }
        } else {
            token = Utils.getToken(creds).accessToken();
        }
        token = iAuthenticationResult.accessToken();
        return siteService.getAllSites(creds, token);
    }
}
```

In my Service layer I also want to do dependency injection with a HttpRequest class :

```
@Service
public class SiteServiceImpl implements SiteService {
    private final HttpRequest httpRequest;

    public SiteServiceImpl(HttpRequest httpRequest) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context =
                new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        this.httpRequest = context.getBean(HttpRequest.class);
    }

    @Override
    public SharePointSiteResponse getAllSites(SharePointCredentialRequest credentialRequest, String token) throws Exception {
        if(Utils.checkToken(token))
            token = Utils.createToken(credentialRequest);

        URL url = new URL("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*");
        return httpRequest.getAllSitesRequest(token, url);
    }
}
```

In my httpRequest class i just build my calls:

```
@Component
public class HttpRequest {
    private final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH").disableHtmlEscaping().create();

    public SharePointSiteResponse getAllSitesRequest(String token, URL url)
            throws IOException, RequestException {
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        return getSiteConnection(token, url, conn);
    }
    ....
```

My AppConfig class is just here for configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages  = {"fr.dsidiff.sharepoint"})
public class AppConfig {
}
```

I obtain an error message :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.resetCommonCaches(AbstractApplicationContext.java:969)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:93)
    at fr.dsidiff.sharepoint.SharePointManager.getInstance(SharePointManager.java:20)
```

Comment: Have you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24237276/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-org-springframework-b ? What dependencies you are using? It would be helpful to see your pom.xml or whatever you are using for dependencies. Also, don't you have to use @Autowired?

Comment: it seems that the bean called by AnnotationConfigApplicationContext can't also called an inner bean using AnnotationConfigApplicationContext. Spring framework version is the latest.

Answer (score 1):

I tried two solutions that solved my issue in my service layer:

```
@Service
public class SiteServiceImpl implements SiteService {
    private final HttpRequest httpRequest;

    @Autowired
    public SiteServiceImpl(HttpRequest httpRequest) {
        this.httpRequest = httpRequest;
    }
 ...
```

I also tried javax @Inject too and it works
I didn't expect i could inject using autowired...